# Specific time range between dates

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause

I want to write a query in SQL Server 2014 that will show me all the rows in specified date range between specific times. I have column `DateCreated` which contains date and time together.

I can easily filter date but I need all rows from these days in specific time range.

Thank you

Comment: Why not `CAST`/`CONVERT` the column to a `time`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Larnu's comment, you can add time range criteria in addition to the desired date range so that results are filtered by the time period as well. Below is an example using inclusive start and exclusive end range criteria:

```
WHERE
    DateCreated >= '20200801' AND DateCreated < '20200831')
    AND CAST(DateCreated AS time) >= '08:00:00' AND CAST(DateCreated AS time) < '16:00:00')
```